# How to do colwise operations in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am doing this a lot:

```
auto f_conj = f.conjugate(); //f is a MatrixXcf, so is C;
for(n=0;n<X.cols();++n)
    C.col(n) = X.col(n).cwiseProduct(f_conj);
```

Am I not supposed to be able to do something like

```
C.colwise() = X.colwise().cwiseProduct(f_conj)
```

instead?

Comment: I guess there is a little mistake in your question and that f is a VectorXcf and not a MatrixXcf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are really doing is a diagonal product, so I'd recommend you the following expression:

```
C = f.conjugate().asDiagonal() * X;
```

If you want to use a colwise() expression, then do not put it on the left hand side:

```
C = X.colwise().cwiseProduct(f.conjugate());
```

Moreover, let me warn you about the use of the auto keyword. Here, let me emphasize that `f_conj` is not a `VectorXcf`, but an expression of the conjugate of a `VectorXcf`. So using `f_conj` or `f.conjugate()` is exactly the same. Since multiplying two complexes or one complex and one conjugate complex amount to the same cost, in this precise case it's ok to use the auto keyword. However, if `f_conj` would be for instance: `auto f_conj = (f+g).conjugate()`, then `f+g` would be recomputed many times in your for loop. Doing `(f+g).conjugate().asDiagonal() * X` is perfectly fine though, because Eigen knows what to do.

Comment: True, didnt think about it as the diagonal of a matrix multiplication. I assume its because of readability you suggest the first? or would i also gain performance?

Comment: mostly for readability, bu also for performance in case X is a row-major matrix.